# python: twisted app with interacive python shell

Tags: python, shell, twisted.internet

Would it be possible to write a twisted-powered application that opens an interactive shell, e.g. to tweak the business objects served via the twisted protocol layer?

My current problem is that the `reactor.run()` blocks the application, and the `IPython.embed()` is only run *after* the reactor has finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you specifically need extras that are only in ipython, you really should check out [manhole](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.manhole.html) (twistedmatrix [example code](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/demo_manhole.tac))

It lets you access a python interactive shell that is natively running in the twisted reactor.  Normally the shell is accessed via telnet or ssh, but if you wanted to be creative you could wire it up any way you want.

Answer (score 2):

... Meanwhile I found an answer to my question: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/threading.html

```
def interact():
   import IPython
   IPython.embed()

reactor.callInThread(interact)
reactor.run()
```